# microphone not working on laptop E 31-80

Tags: laptop, lenovo, microphone

my microphone is not working on this new lenovo laptop, when doing a skype test call it makes some static sound.
I even bought an external microphone and it doesn't work either...
Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: not one guess our direction to look into?

Answer (score 0):

Solved following this instrucions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting#Line_Input.2FMicrophone_Troubleshooting